# How to deal with Parent/Child/GrandChild relationship?

Tags: c#, enumerable

I am looking for a way to represent an object that has a Parent, a Child, and a grandchild object. I do not want to use:

```
 IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Node>>>
```

If it is at all possible.

Each Node is the same:

```
public class Node
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

I need to represent a tree like structure where there are three levels of data. Ex

```
 ParentNode
     ChildNode

 ParentNode
     ChildNode
         GrandChildNode
         GrandChildNode
```

I am trying to do this as generically / clean as possible so that I can reuse the service that gets this information from the database.

Any Sugestions?

Comment: And why don't you want to use a nested IEnumerable?

Comment: Add a `Children` property to `Node` that is an `IEnumerable<Children>` and a `Parent` property that is of type `Node`.

Comment: @gunr2171 It is very convoluted to have multiple nested lists and its hard to read and follow most times

Comment: @ASAD So have an interface (INode) and have three separate objects that build the structure?

Comment: @Robert No, just one class is required; unless you actually need to have differing properties at different levels in the hierarchy, which you say in your question you don't.

Comment: @ASAD They are all the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify your class to accommodate a tree like hierarchy.

```
public class Node
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Node Parent { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<Node> Children { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<Node> Ancestors() {
        Node current = this.Parent;
        while (current != null) {
            yield return current;
            current = current.Parent;                
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Node> Descendants() {
        foreach (Node c in this.Children) {
            yield return c;
            foreach (Node d in c.Descendants())
                yield return d;
        }
    }

    // Root node constructor
    public Node() {
        this.Children = new List<Node>();     
    }

    // Child node constructor
    public Node(Node parent) : this() {
        this.Parent = parent;
        parent.Children.Add(this);
    }
}
```

You can then use it like so:

```
Node gramps = new Node() { Title = "Grandparent" };
Node dad = new Node(gramps) { Title = "Parent" };
Node son = new Node(dad) { Title = "Child" };
```